# Memory address in dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int anything[] = {5};
  int *something = new int;
  *something = 5;

  std::cout << &anything  << "==" << &anything[0]  << "==" << anything  << std::endl;
  std::cout << &something << "!=" << &something[0] << "==" << something << std::endl;
}
```

Why is the memory address in `&something` different from `&something[0]` and `something`? Although it is a dynamic allocation, I don't understand why the memory address is different. I tried it with more than one value; it's the same thing. Here I used one value for both for simplicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&something` is the memory address of the pointer itself (hey, it needs to store that value somewhere!), while `&something[0]` is the address of the actual memory that is storing your stuff.

Comment: but anything is also a pointer, right ? for instance, if I change &anything to &(*anything) it remains equal, the memory address of the first pointer itself is equal to &anything[0] and anything. In dynamic allocation, something, why the pointer itself has a different memory address ?

Comment: No; `anything` is an array, not a pointer.  In many, but not all, contexts, a reference to `array` is equivalent to a pointer.  One of the contexts where there is a difference is as the operand of (unary) `&`.

Answer (score 2):

`something` is a pointer. `&something` is the address of that pointer. `&something[0]` is the address of the first element pointed to by the pointer, which is completely different from the address of the pointer. `something` is the value of the pointer, which is also the address of the element that is pointed to.

I'm sure this topic has been covered many times before, I hope I did it justice.